how to resolve wheel setup issue during any liabries install in jupyter notebook
how to resolve  wheel setup issue during any liabries install in jupyter notebook
!pip install langchain
!pip install -U setuptools
!python -m pip install --upgrade pip
!python -m pip install --use-pep517 google.colab
!pip install transformers
#!pip install mariadb
!pip install mariadb==1.0.11

Requirement already satisfied: langchain in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (0.2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML>=5.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from langchain) (6.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: SQLAlchemy<3,>=1.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from langchain) (2.0.30)
Requirement already satisfied: aiohttp<4.0.0,>=3.8.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from langchain) (3.9.5)
Requirement already satisfied: async-timeout<5.0.0,>=4.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from langchain) (4.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: langchain-core<0.3.0,>=0.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from langchain) (0.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: langchain-text-splitters<0.3.0,>=0.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from langchain) (0.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: langsmith<0.2.0,>=0.1.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from langchain) (0.1.76)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<2,>=1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from langchain) (1.25.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pydantic<3,>=1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from langchain) (2.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3,>=2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from langchain) (2.31.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tenacity<9.0.0,>=8.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from langchain) (8.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: aiosignal>=1.1.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from aiohttp<4.0.0,>=3.8.3->langchain) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from aiohttp<4.0.0,>=3.8.3->langchain) (23.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: frozenlist>=1.1.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from aiohttp<4.0.0,>=3.8.3->langchain) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: multidict<7.0,>=4.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from aiohttp<4.0.0,>=3.8.3->langchain) (6.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: yarl<2.0,>=1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from aiohttp<4.0.0,>=3.8.3->langchain) (1.9.4)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonpatch<2.0,>=1.33 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from langchain-core<0.3.0,>=0.2.0->langchain) (1.33)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging<24.0,>=23.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from langchain-core<0.3.0,>=0.2.0->langchain) (23.2)
Requirement already satisfied: orjson<4.0.0,>=3.9.14 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from langsmith<0.2.0,>=0.1.17->langchain) (3.10.4)
Requirement already satisfied: annotated-types>=0.4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from pydantic<3,>=1->langchain) (0.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pydantic-core==2.18.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from pydantic<3,>=1->langchain) (2.18.4)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=4.6.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from pydantic<3,>=1->langchain) (4.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests<3,>=2->langchain) (3.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests<3,>=2->langchain) (3.7)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests<3,>=2->langchain) (2.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests<3,>=2->langchain) (2024.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: greenlet!=0.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from SQLAlchemy<3,>=1.4->langchain) (3.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonpointer>=1.9 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from jsonpatch<2.0,>=1.33->langchain-core<0.3.0,>=0.2.0->langchain) (3.0.0)
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (70.0.0)
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (24.0)
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
Requirement already satisfied: google.colab in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth==2.27.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from google.colab) (2.27.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel==5.5.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from google.colab) (5.5.6)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython==7.34.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from google.colab) (7.34.0)
Requirement already satisfied: notebook==6.5.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from google.colab) (6.5.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas==2.0.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from google.colab) (2.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: portpicker==1.5.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from google.colab) (1.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: requests==2.31.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from google.colab) (2.31.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado==6.3.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from google.colab) (6.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: cachetools<6.0,>=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from google-auth==2.27.0->google.colab) (5.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from google-auth==2.27.0->google.colab) (0.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: rsa<5,>=3.1.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from google-auth==2.27.0->google.colab) (4.9)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ipykernel==5.5.6->google.colab) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ipykernel==5.5.6->google.colab) (5.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-client in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ipykernel==5.5.6->google.colab) (6.1.12)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ipython==7.34.0->google.colab) (70.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jedi>=0.16 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ipython==7.34.0->google.colab) (0.19.1)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ipython==7.34.0->google.colab) (4.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pickleshare in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ipython==7.34.0->google.colab) (0.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ipython==7.34.0->google.colab) (3.0.45)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ipython==7.34.0->google.colab) (2.16.1)
Requirement already satisfied: backcall in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ipython==7.34.0->google.colab) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib-inline in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ipython==7.34.0->google.colab) (0.1.7)
Requirement already satisfied: pexpect>4.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ipython==7.34.0->google.colab) (4.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (3.1.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq<25,>=17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (24.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: argon2-cffi in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (23.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-core>=4.6.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (5.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: nbformat in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (5.10.4)
Requirement already satisfied: nbconvert>=5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (6.5.4)
Requirement already satisfied: nest-asyncio>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (1.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Send2Trash>=1.8.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (1.8.3)
Requirement already satisfied: terminado>=0.8.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (0.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: prometheus-client in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (0.20.0)
Requirement already satisfied: nbclassic>=0.4.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from pandas==2.0.3->google.colab) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from pandas==2.0.3->google.colab) (2023.4)
Requirement already satisfied: tzdata>=2022.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from pandas==2.0.3->google.colab) (2024.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.21.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from pandas==2.0.3->google.colab) (1.25.2)
Requirement already satisfied: psutil in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from portpicker==1.5.2->google.colab) (5.9.5)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests==2.31.0->google.colab) (3.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests==2.31.0->google.colab) (3.7)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests==2.31.0->google.colab) (2.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests==2.31.0->google.colab) (2024.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: parso<0.9.0,>=0.8.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from jedi>=0.16->ipython==7.34.0->google.colab) (0.8.4)
Requirement already satisfied: platformdirs>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from jupyter-core>=4.6.1->notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (4.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: notebook-shim>=0.2.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from nbclassic>=0.4.7->notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (0.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (4.9.4)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (4.12.3)
Requirement already satisfied: bleach in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (6.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: defusedxml in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: entrypoints>=0.2.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyterlab-pygments in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (0.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (2.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: mistune<2,>=0.8.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (0.8.4)
Requirement already satisfied: nbclient>=0.5.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (23.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pandocfilters>=1.4.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (1.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tinycss2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from nbconvert>=5->notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: fastjsonschema>=2.15 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from nbformat->notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (2.19.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema>=2.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from nbformat->notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (4.19.2)
Requirement already satisfied: ptyprocess>=0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from pexpect>4.3->ipython==7.34.0->google.colab) (0.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from prompt-toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0->ipython==7.34.0->google.colab) (0.2.13)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1<0.7.0,>=0.4.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1->google-auth==2.27.0->google.colab) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.2->pandas==2.0.3->google.colab) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: argon2-cffi-bindings in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from argon2-cffi->notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (21.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=22.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from jsonschema>=2.6->nbformat->notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (23.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema-specifications>=2023.03.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from jsonschema>=2.6->nbformat->notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (2023.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: referencing>=0.28.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from jsonschema>=2.6->nbformat->notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (0.35.1)
Requirement already satisfied: rpds-py>=0.7.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from jsonschema>=2.6->nbformat->notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (0.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-server<3,>=1.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from notebook-shim>=0.2.3->nbclassic>=0.4.7->notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (1.24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from argon2-cffi-bindings->argon2-cffi->notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from beautifulsoup4->nbconvert>=5->notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: webencodings in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from bleach->nbconvert>=5->notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from cffi>=1.0.1->argon2-cffi-bindings->argon2-cffi->notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (2.22)
Requirement already satisfied: anyio<4,>=3.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from jupyter-server<3,>=1.8->notebook-shim>=0.2.3->nbclassic>=0.4.7->notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (3.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: websocket-client in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from jupyter-server<3,>=1.8->notebook-shim>=0.2.3->nbclassic>=0.4.7->notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (1.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: sniffio>=1.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from anyio<4,>=3.1.0->jupyter-server<3,>=1.8->notebook-shim>=0.2.3->nbclassic>=0.4.7->notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: exceptiongroup in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from anyio<4,>=3.1.0->jupyter-server<3,>=1.8->notebook-shim>=0.2.3->nbclassic>=0.4.7->notebook==6.5.5->google.colab) (1.2.1)
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
Requirement already satisfied: transformers in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (4.41.2)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from transformers) (3.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: huggingface-hub<1.0,>=0.23.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from transformers) (0.23.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from transformers) (1.25.2)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from transformers) (23.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml>=5.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from transformers) (6.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: regex!=2019.12.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from transformers) (2024.5.15)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from transformers) (2.31.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tokenizers<0.20,>=0.19 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from transformers) (0.19.1)
Requirement already satisfied: safetensors>=0.4.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from transformers) (0.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm>=4.27 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from transformers) (4.66.4)
Requirement already satisfied: fsspec>=2023.5.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from huggingface-hub<1.0,>=0.23.0->transformers) (2023.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.7.4.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from huggingface-hub<1.0,>=0.23.0->transformers) (4.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests->transformers) (3.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests->transformers) (3.7)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests->transformers) (2.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests->transformers) (2024.6.2)
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
Collecting mariadb==1.0.11
  Downloading mariadb-1.0.11.zip (85 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 85.9/85.9 kB 2.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

please give me some ans

looks like it has an error while downloading. Is that the complete output you get? Can you try pip install -v mariadb==1.0.11

Please update your approaches to not be using outdated practices. It may not help here; however, you'll have a better experience in modern Jupyter and make your post useful for more users. In 2019, the magic %pip install variation was added to ensure the installation occurs in the environment where the kernel is actually running. The exclamation point in conjunction with an install command doesn't insure this and can lead to issues.  See more about the modern ...

 %pip install command here. The second paragraph here goes into more details about why the exclamation point may lead to issues.
